# Why isn't Microsoft ludown recognised on my machine?

Tags: windows, terminal, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to convert a markdown lu file to a JSON file to pass into my LUIS app, however when I run any ludown command the following error occurs:

```
ludown parse to luis -h
```

> ludown : The term 'ludown' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> ```
> + ludown parse to luis -h
> + ~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ludown:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

I have carried out a global install of ludown using `npm install -g ludown`

Any ideas on why my machine is not recognising ludown after the install?

Comment: Is `node` in your `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'npm install -g ludown' command, it will show that the package has been successfully installed, but when you check for the version or try any other command, you will get an error ' **'ludown' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**'

- You will need to change the directory, which in this case is 'npm' and then execute the installation command followed by 'ludown parse'.
- For example, in my case it was **'C:\Users\USER_NAME\App Data\Roaming\npm'**(replace the USER_NAME to your username in the system). Once you change your directory to npm, you can install ludown using **'npm install -g ludown'**. You can check for the ludown version by executing '**ludown -v'** and then use the 'ludown parse toluis -h' command to convert a markdown lu file to a JSON file to pass into your LUIS app.